# Segmentation fault in C get line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getline

I need to read a file and for that I am using the function getline. The following is an example from this website: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html that I tempered with in order to be able to open a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
  {
  int bytes_read;
  unsigned long nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;
  char *filename;
  char *line;
  FILE *fd = NULL;


  puts ("enter filename");

  filename = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);

  bytes_read = getline (&filename, &nbytes, stdin);

  fd = fopen(filename, "r");

  bytes_read = getline (&line, &nbytes, fd);

  puts (line);

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
  else
    {
      puts ("You typed:");
      puts (my_string);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

and when I run the program I get a Segmentation fault 11, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Always check that you opened the file successfully.  You didn't remove the newline from the string returned by get line so you probably didn't open a file with a newline at the end of its name.

Comment: Also, it is conventional to use `fd` for a file descriptor (of type `int`) and `fp` for a file pointer (stream — of type `FILE *`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filename` read from stdin is wrong for a file file argument. For example, the `filename` get str value from stdin is 'a.txt\n', when input `a.txt`.

So, adding a statement the modify the '\n' with '\0' will solve the problem. That is adding `filename[bytes_read - 1] = '\0';` statement right below the `bytes_read = getline (&filename, &nbytes, stdin);` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
  {
  int bytes_read;
  unsigned long nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;
  char *filename;
  char *line;
  FILE *fd = NULL;


  puts ("enter filename");

  filename = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);

  bytes_read = getline (&filename, &nbytes, stdin);

  filename[bytes_read - 1] = '\0';

  fd = fopen(filename, "r");

  bytes_read = getline (&line, &nbytes, fd);

  puts (line);

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
  else
    {
      puts ("You typed:");
      puts (my_string);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the "bug" in fact was the omitting of error checking.

Comment: This solution will fail if you press just Ctrl-D instead of inputting a name followed by Enter.

Comment: Anyways the `fgets()`ish `\n` is a nice catch which I missed. :-)

Comment: You want to test `bytes_read` against `0` before substrating from an `unsigned`.

Comment: @alk Yes here the code has many more condition checking work to do. Here just to make it run with the presuppositions.

Comment: And thanks for the detail instruction for getline usage. Also this code should  never be throwed into production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Either

- make `line` point to some valid memory and `nbytes` to the memory's size

or

- or set `line` to `NULL` and `nbytes` to `0`.

From [`man getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> ```
> ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **getline**() reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into *lineptr.  The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.
>
> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then **getline**() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.

Also `getline()` expects a `size_t` as 2nd parameter not an `unsigned long`.

Also^2 there is no need to allcocate 1 byte more then being passed to `getline`. Allocate `n` bytes and pass `n`, no need to pass `n - 1`.

---

And always add error checking to relevant system call, like `malloc()` and `fopen()` before using the result they return.

Comment: hi @alk, this is not what cause the segfault, though getline call argument should be checked. This answer is too general.

Comment: This call would definitely invoke UB and with this anything can from this second call to `getline()` on, including a segmentation violation. Also I feel this isn't "*general*" at all, but pointing out a very specific bug in the code shown. @lulyon

Comment: Even tough that was wrong, I think the error is in the get line(&filename, &nbytes, stdin) because the error is right when I enter the filename.

Comment: @alk The specific bug cause is way before the getline call, with the wrong filename.

Comment: @lulyon: What's wrong with `filename`? This is not a guessing games here.

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong is, when I call fopen, for some reason, I cannot open the fd, after checking, the fd is still NULL

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @alk sorry, a little network problem. I checked filename value, note that the value is 'input.txt\n', which is not the intended file path argument for getline.      check my answer for detail.